# Python : editing several files : loop on a list of file

Tags: python, csv, io

Hy everyone,

I have thousands of three column .csv Ascii files with this format:

```
"1;6774.64;210.00"
```

I would like to transform them into do a list I can edit into python like this :

> [6774.64, 210.00]

I've starded to try to do some import like :

```
p = open('ruby-Ne008.csv')
linelist = [line for line in p.readlines()]
```

but then how to remove the " character , and replace the ; character as a column separator.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> with open('ruby-Ne008.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ';' )
    lis = list(chain.from_iterable(map(float,row[1:]) for row in reader))
    print lis
...     
[6774.64, 210.0]
```

Comment: For clarity and readability of code I'd propose to now just use `row` but the true meanings of the values, e. g.: `list(chain.from_iterable([ float(height), float(width) ] for count, height, width in reader))`  (But of course we don't know the names, so that's up to the asker.)

Answer (score 1):

`linelist = [[float(x) for x in line.split(';')[1:]] for line in p.readlines()]`

Is that good enough?